# C# Blazor server - why so many _blazor requests and such memory consumption?

Tags: c#, memory-management, python-requests, blazor, blazor-server-side

The context:
I wrote a small server side app in .net 5 to fetch json file from API and reconstruct it to a nice and readable table (with two Syncfusion card components and two tabs). Other than that there is a small component with image and some text from local file and main page which is empty. Navmenu is simple with no flashy stuff.

The problem:
When I test the app on localhost it works just fine. However when I publish it to folder and deploy to server (Ubuntu with apache) all kinds of weird stuff happens. App idling takes 22GB (VIRT) of memory in htop, just after starting the service it already has +/- 20 instances of .dll file running (also htop). Upon trying to connect via browser the number of instances goes up by a few.

Also when trying to connect to the app in the browser I see many requests to _blazor?id=someRandomID and most of them are failed, this doesn't happen in testing on localhost.

Can someone explain to me why so many requests to _blazor and why such a huge memory consumption if there is nobobdy using the app? It's not like there are some huge files being loaded there, those json files are mostly < 1MB.

Comment: Have you tried a default/blank blazor app that doesn't have any of your code in it?

Comment: Did you enable WebSockets?

Comment: @Neil - nope, haven't thought of that, will definitely try this tomorrow.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - it's my first deploy of a web app, not sure what you mean but I do use IHttpClientFactory for any outside requests and have configured services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddHubOptions(options =>{blablabla}). In terms of communicating with the app I understand, might be wrong here, that SignalR somewhat replaces raw web sockets as it uses web sockets whenever possible.

Comment: WebSockets would be an Apache setting.

Comment: Thanks for help, I just tested @Neil idea and deployed an empty template and it behaves exactly the same as my app which would indicate this is expected. Also I was reading up on top and it seems VIRT is the max amount of memory a program can access, actual used memory size is much smaller and in the next column in htop.