# Blazor Server app with many requests make website unstable

Tags: c#, blazor

I created Blazor server web app and I deployed on Azure App Service, and in `Network` tab I see alot of requests to `https://mywebsites0123.azurewebsites.net/_blazor?id=3OO-T6L4Bu9bMRF8QAo_5Q&_=166722` and make application unstable.

On localhost (Debug and Release) I cannot find any request and application is working smooth.

I read this [C# Blazor server - why so many _blazor requests and such memory consumption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67671634/c-sharp-blazor-server-why-so-many-blazor-requests-and-such-memory-consumption) but can't find solution.

The startup page looks like:

`ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

```
 services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

services.AddSignalR(e =>
{
                e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 2000 * 1024;
});

// Radzen init
services.AddScoped<DialogService>();
services.AddScoped<TooltipService>();
services.AddScoped<NotificationService>();

services.AddMemoryCache();

var apiScope = Configuration["Authentication:ApiScope"];
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "Authentication:AzureAd")
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { apiScope })
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
services.AddAuthorization();
```

and

`Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

I receive alot of requests:
[image]

After few seconds later:

[image]

And then number of requests continue to increase. Don't know why this happens when app is hosted on Azure app service.

Any tips to look for ?

Solution:

Enable on Azure AppService the WebSockets (by default is Off) described: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/publish-to-azure-web-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-the-app-in-azure-app-service

[image]

Comment: What do you mean **specifically** with _"make application unstable"_? What's the purpose of all the custom configuration you have in ConfigureServices? "Many requests" is subjective. Is it one million per second? 15 per hour? The "id" calls are part of the handshaking.

Comment: Around 3500 calls within one minute, after a while, on the page, appear Refresh button because of timeout, due to many requests. Unstable I mean that page is disconnected, and for every dropdown/selection the _blazor request is called 10 times for one component

Comment: This seems to be a connectivity issue. Blazor is losing the websocket connection and reconnecting. There might be a configuration issue with your server, where continuous connections aren't guaranteed. I would enable Blazor/SignalR client and server-side debugging to get all the reconnection/warning/error messages. And if you don't have any logging infrastructure in place: now's a good time to implement it. Trust me, you'll need it more often in the future.

Comment: Check the IP addresses of the requests.  On my MS VM, I had to disable all traffic from Chinese IP addresses, as I was getting absolutely bombarded.

Comment: Solved: I posted solution in OP

Comment: Answer your own question instead. Updating the question makes it look like there is no solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

Enable on Azure AppService the WebSockets (by default is Off) described: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/publish-to-azure-web-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-the-app-in-azure-app-service

[image]